# Errors in struct in c

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have made two structs,

Struct1:

`struct candy {
    char *colour;
    struct cadny *next;
};`

Struct 2:

`struct result {
    struct candy *container1;
    struct candy *container2;
};`

I have written a function which takes two pointers of type struct1, and returns a struct2.

But,

`struct result r = removeCandy (container1, container2);
container1 = r -> container1;
container2 = r -> container2;`

While doing this in main function, I am getting error,

`1.c:44:18: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct result’)
   container1 = r -> container1;
                  ^
1.c:45:18: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct result’)
   container2 = r -> container2;`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try using dot (.) instead of (->)

Comment: It is working now.

Comment: But, dont both things are same?

Comment: No they are not. -> is used to access the attributes of the thing that is pointed by the pointer on the left of ->, but here r is not a pointer, but a struct, whose attributes are to be accessed.

Comment: Thanks. You may answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: Can't. It is marked as an exact duplicate now.

Comment: 'result' is user defined data type. r is reference variable of result datatype. Now if you want to access result by using reference variable 'r'. Then you will have to use reference operator '.'. By using dot you can access result data type.  

Now if you want to use -> operator. Then declare r as pointer.
struct result *r. now you can access by -> operator.